# firebase hosting react + firebase functions express

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a problem with correct config firebase.JSON

1)
in folder build have react app, in firebase functions have an app with the express

```
    "rewrites": [
      {
    "source" : "/admin",
    "function" : "app"
  },
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

this works only on safari - in chrome it doesn't why and how to solve it ?

2) 
why this config

```
    "rewrites": [
      {
    "source" : "/admin/**",
    "function" : "app"
  }]
```

doesn't work to express app